# Can you mix two documents in one book?

Tags: adobe-indesign, book, layout

I am translating a book from latin and want to put the translation on the next page (parallel text edition) keeping different footnotes for each document. I have two documents in one book, latin.indd and english.indd. Is there a way to mix the content of the two indd-s in the book, or can you suggest a better way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading solutions in other posts I realised the solution was simple. I imported two word documents (latin and english translation) in one indesign document and then placed the first in the odd pages and the second in the even pages, having two flows for each variant. I can now modify them so the texts (latin and english) correspond.

Answer (score 0):

While it's possible to place one InDesign document into another, I would really suggest that you at least consider exporting the text from both as Adobe Tagged Text and then reimporting them into a new document.

Then, for each text flow, create and assign Conditions to each (Latin, English).

Then, once you have everything stitched together as a seamless whole you can use the Conditional Text feature to turn one language or the other on/off and you can have all three book variants (Latin, English, dual) in a single document so that updates to one will be reflected in the others.